# Java: Class does not have a main method

Tags: java

I am unable to figure out where to put a main method in the class `DrawMePanel`.

```java
package draw;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawMePanel extends JPanel
{   
  for ( int topLeft = 0; topLeft < 80; topLeft += 10 )
  {
     int radius = 160 - ( topLeft * 2 );
     g.drawArc( topLeft + 10, topLeft + 25, radius, radius, 0, 360 );
  } // end for
    }
```

Here is the other Java class associated with this:

```java
package draw;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class DrawMe extends JFrame
{
   public static void main( String args[] )
   {
  // create frame for CirclesJPanel
      JFrame frame = new JFrame( "Draw Me" );
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

      DrawMePanel circlesJPanel = new DrawMePanel();
      frame.add( circlesJPanel ); // add circlesJPanel to frame
      frame.setSize( 200, 250 ); // set frame size
      frame.setVisible( true ); // display frame
   } // end main
}
```

When I try to run the `DrawMePanel`, it says-

> Class "draw.DrawMePanel" does not have a main method.

When running the `DrawMe` class I receive this error:

> run: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Duplicate field name&signature in
>   class file draw/DrawMePanel   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2693)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3040)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3010)   at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1776)    at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
>     at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
>   Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total
>   time: 2 seconds)

Comment: Run the DrawMe class, this has the main method...

Comment: Is it just me or shouldn't DrawMePanel not compile? (you're executing code out side of an executable context)

Comment: When i run the DrawMe class, i get a really long error. I added it to the main question because it was too long for this comment. There seems to be a method missing from DrawMePanel

Comment: Run DrawMe and the game will start

Comment: I added public void DrawMePanel(Graphics g) to DrawMePanel and now i can run DrawMe with no errors

Answer (score 0):

Instinctively I trust the error message. And looking at your code, I think you are safe to run `DrawMe` instead. This **contains** a main method, and references/creates one of `DrawMePanel`.

Comment: I tried running DrawMe, and received a long error. I added it to the main question. There seems to be some sort of method missing from DrawMePanel

Comment: always trust (most) the latest error message! ;) "Duplicate field name&signature in class file draw/DrawMePanel" (a hint: look for differences between your question post and the current code)

Answer (score 0):

You can't run the `DrawMePanel` without it having a `main` method (which is the [Entry Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point) to your Java program). Currently your `DrawMe` class has the `main()` method. You can run that, or copy the `main()` method to the `DrawMePanel` (Java projects can have multiple classes with `main()` methods).

[JLS-12.1.4 - Invoke `Test.main`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4) says in part,

> The method `main` must be declared `public`, `static`, and `void`. It must specify a formal parameter ([§8.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1)) whose declared type is array of `String`. Therefore, either of the following declarations is acceptable:
>
> ```
> public static void main(String[] args)
>
> public static void main(String... args)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Put your main method in your DrawMe class. You don't need to have a class for main method. In java it's just the entry point where the program start to run.